# Finding length of string using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int length=0;
    printf("Enter string :\n");
    scanf("%c",str);
    while(*str)
    {
        length++;
        *str++;
    }
    printf("%d",length);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write a program to find length of string using pointers.But whatever the string, I'm getting the result as 1. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: %c reads a single character. Use %s.

Comment: also, `str++`, not `*str++`

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca I think that's fine. `++` has higher precedence than `*`

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @AdrianTam Actually, that will increase the pointer and that is what leads to the UB. So, maybe not so fine.

Comment: If you want to read a *line* of input, then use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Besides solving your problem, it will also solve other *potential* problems.

Comment: Finally, don't do the counting yourself. Use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: Why does it lead to UB? aren't we incrementing the pointer to find the null terminator?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I would say that you don't *need* to dereference while incrementing in this case. It's an additional operation when the desired outcome is just to increment the pointer, but a decent compiler should optimize the dereference right out.

Comment: With your current code there might not *be* a null-terminator. So the incrementing of the pointer will make you use uninitialized parts of the memory. And the contents of that memory is *indeterminate* (and should be seen as almost random or "garbage"). That could lead you to go out of bounds.

Comment: @GovindParmar ok, but it obfuscates the meaning of the code, at best.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so how does dereferencing it help in case null terminator is not present?Will it stop at the ubound of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate 100 bytes ok

```
char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

int length=0;
printf("Enter string :\n");
```

You have a string but read one character

```
scanf("%c",str);
```

While that character is != 0 You increment the character with one e.g. 'A' becomes 'B' and so on the character overflows

```
while(*str)
{
    length++;
    *str++;
```

---

Instead, read a string using fgets()

```
const int maxlen = 100;
char *str=malloc(maxlen); 

if (fgets(str,maxlen,stdin) != NULL)
{
  // now to calculate the length
  int length = 0;
  char* p = str;  // use a temp ptr so you can free str 
  while (*p++) 
  { 
    ++length; 
  }
  printf("length=%d", length);
  free(str); // to avoid memory leak
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` modifier in `scanf` reads character sequences. As you did not provide a field width, it reads by default only one character per time. You might want to use the `%s` modifier.

Further, when no length modifier is added, the returned character sequence is not null terminated, which makes your loop to determine the length risky (you also might want to use the `strlen` function from the C standard library, but this function also expects a null terminated sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your scanf.

```
char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

printf("Enter string :\n");
scanf("%s",str);
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'; i ++)
{
}
printf("%d",i);
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And add a length-modifier to the format so the buffer won't be overrun. And always check what `scanf` returns.

Comment: If I do not cast the malloc some compiles would give me an error. I tried with GCC 8.2. I did not try to optimize OPs code, just make it run. But you are generally right - C and memory needs some attention to be safe.

Comment: Then you're using C++ and not C.